# PHP stripping letters with accents/weird letters and changing them by normal letters

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I'm using the PHPUNit selenium webdriver from Sebastian Bergmann.

So what I basically do is:

I get a random name of a random name generator and I get for example:
*Josh Parker*

I explode these into first and lastname

```
$fullname = explode(' ', $thename);
$firstname = $fullname[count($fullname)-1];
$lastname = $fullname[count($fullname)-2];
// I should strip the names from accents and weird letters
```

Using this name I create an email to fill in a form. The email will be: josh.parker@ourdomain.com

The issue is that the field doesn't accept any accents or wierd letters on letters such as **ä ö ô Æ è é ù** etc ...
So if I get a random name like: *Régis Olivier*

When I implode this into an email

```
$domain = '@domain.be';

$array5 = array($firstname, $lastname);
$fullnameuser = implode("-", $array5);

$array7 = array($fullnameuser, $domain);
$genemail = implode("", $array7);
```

The outcome would be: Olivier.Régis@domain.be
Because of the `é` in this user his name the field won't accept it.

Is there anyway that I can check for letters with accents and change them into an normal letter?
I'm not sure about all letters, I had issues with the letter  `Æ and ç` aswell.

*é , è --> e*

*ç --> c*

*Æ --> ae* `// Hoping special characters like this would be changed too and not just accents`

*ù --> u*

*â --> a*

Etc ...

Comment: Surely you can **remove them**, but not sure you can replace them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accent stripping is not something easy because there is no (at least to my knowledge) ready-made solution in PHP.

A classic solution would look like this:

```
function removeAccents(str) {
    var find, re;
    var a = ['À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ø', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ý', 'ÿ', 'Ā', 'ā', 'Ă', 'ă', 'Ą', 'ą', 'Ć', 'ć', 'Ĉ', 'ĉ', 'Ċ', 'ċ', 'Č', 'č', 'Ď', 'ď', 'Đ', 'đ', 'Ē', 'ē', 'Ĕ', 'ĕ', 'Ė', 'ė', 'Ę', 'ę', 'Ě', 'ě', 'Ĝ', 'ĝ', 'Ğ', 'ğ', 'Ġ', 'ġ', 'Ģ', 'ģ', 'Ĥ', 'ĥ', 'Ħ', 'ħ', 'Ĩ', 'ĩ', 'Ī', 'ī', 'Ĭ', 'ĭ', 'Į', 'į', 'İ', 'ı', 'Ĳ', 'ĳ', 'Ĵ', 'ĵ', 'Ķ', 'ķ', 'Ĺ', 'ĺ', 'Ļ', 'ļ', 'Ľ', 'ľ', 'Ŀ', 'ŀ', 'Ł', 'ł', 'Ń', 'ń', 'Ņ', 'ņ', 'Ň', 'ň', 'ŉ', 'Ō', 'ō', 'Ŏ', 'ŏ', 'Ő', 'ő', 'Œ', 'œ', 'Ŕ', 'ŕ', 'Ŗ', 'ŗ', 'Ř', 'ř', 'Ś', 'ś', 'Ŝ', 'ŝ', 'Ş', 'ş', 'Š', 'š', 'Ţ', 'ţ', 'Ť', 'ť', 'Ŧ', 'ŧ', 'Ũ', 'ũ', 'Ū', 'ū', 'Ŭ', 'ŭ', 'Ů', 'ů', 'Ű', 'ű', 'Ų', 'ų', 'Ŵ', 'ŵ', 'Ŷ', 'ŷ', 'Ÿ', 'Ź', 'ź', 'Ż', 'ż', 'Ž', 'ž', 'ſ', 'ƒ', 'Ơ', 'ơ', 'Ư', 'ư', 'Ǎ', 'ǎ', 'Ǐ', 'ǐ', 'Ǒ', 'ǒ', 'Ǔ', 'ǔ', 'Ǖ', 'ǖ', 'Ǘ', 'ǘ', 'Ǚ', 'ǚ', 'Ǜ', 'ǜ', 'Ǻ', 'ǻ', 'Ǽ', 'ǽ', 'Ǿ', 'ǿ', 'Ά', 'ά', 'Έ', 'έ', 'Ό', 'ό', 'Ώ', 'ώ', 'Ί', 'ί', 'ϊ', 'ΐ', 'Ύ', 'ύ', 'ϋ', 'ΰ', 'Ή', 'ή'];
    var b = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'AE', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'D', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'Y', 's', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'y', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'IJ', 'ij', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'OE', 'oe', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'W', 'w', 'Y', 'y', 'Y', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 's', 'f', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'AE', 'ae', 'O', 'o', 'Α', 'α', 'Ε', 'ε', 'Ο', 'ο', 'Ω', 'ω', 'Ι', 'ι', 'ι', 'ι', 'Υ', 'υ', 'υ', 'υ', 'Η', 'η'];
    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        find = 'abc';
        re = new RegExp(a[i], 'g');
        str = str.replace(re, b[i]);
    }
  return str;
}
```